# Traefik: Dynamic routing by subdomain

Tags: routes, traefik

**Problem,**

I have multiple services that are deployed on Docker containers. Each set of our clients should be routed to a specific service.
Example:

- Client1 -> service1
- Client2 -> service1
- client3 -> service2

This should done using subdomain:
client1= client1.example.com
client2 = client2.example.com

**Question:**

I would like this config to be dynamic meaning that Traefik needs to get these routing rules dynamically from another service:

- I can for example create a service that giving a hostname return the
  name of service that Traefik should route to.
- Or maybe when a client is added I can push this rule to Traefik.

**Details:**

This feature is useful when I create a saas application.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

One easy way to achieve this is to use regex for the defined routers for each of the services and update the regex once you onboarded a new client

For instance, add this label to the service 1

```
 - traefik.http.routers.app-backend.rule=HostRegexp(`{subdomain:(clinet1)}.example.com`)
```

and when you add another client that should be served by service 1, just update the label to be

```
 - traefik.http.routers.app-backend.rule=HostRegexp(`{subdomain:(clinet1|clientX)}.example.com`)
```

Comment: In that case I need to restart the service which is something I don't prefer.

Comment: no, you do not need to restart it. you can add these labels with the below command `docker service update $service --label-add $lable`

Comment: Is there no other way? Like a wildcard?

Comment: you can try to do ``- traefik.http.routers.app-backend.rule=HostRegexp(`{subdomain:(.*)}.example.com`)
``